# Troubleshooting SSH Tunnel to Connect to Private EKS Subnets in GitLab CI/CD

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am working on setting up an EKS (Elastic Kubernetes Service) module in private subnets using GitLab CI/CD. In my CI/CD pipeline, I need to connect to the EKS cluster. To do this, I understand that I must be able to access the private endpoints via the VPC.

I've considered using a VPN, but I'd prefer a simpler solution. I thought of using a public EC2 instance as a tunnel to reach the private subnets.

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

Created an EC2 instance in the public subnet.
Added the PEM file and set its permissions using `chmod 600`.
I intend to use this EC2 instance as a tunnel by running terraform apply on the eks module.
To establish the tunnel, I ran the following command in my terminal:

```
ssh -i ./myKey.pem -N -L 8022:127.0.0.1:443 ubuntu@<public EC2 IP>
```

Then, in another terminal, I ran:

```
telnet <private IP of another EC2 instance> 443
```

However, it's stuck on the message:

```
Trying...
```

Could someone please help me understand why it's not working or if I missed any steps? I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions to make this setup work as intended.